# yii2 right sql command to perfom my query

Tags: yii2

I am trying to get data from `user_request_wallet` table where lead_developer = ? and answer_tocall be ? or be ? and I want to join `mainRequest` table to it.

How should be it command ???

I tried 2 way but not success

```
//$model = UserRequestWallet::find()->Where(['and',['lead_developer' => $getUser]])
//->andWhere(['and',['answer_tocall' => 'accepted']])
//->andWhere(['or',['answer_tocall' => 'putonhold']])
//->joinWith('mainRequest');

$model = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select('*')
->from('user_request_wallet')
->andwhere(['lead_developer'=> $getUser])->andWhere(['answer_tocall' => 'accepted'])
->orWhere(['answer_tocall'=>'putonhold'])->leftJoin('mainRequest');
```

Header say

```
Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ((`lead_developer`=7) AND (`answer_tocall`='accepted')) OR (`answer_tocall' at line 1
```

The SQL being executed was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_request_wallet` LEFT JOIN `mainRequest` WHERE ((`lead_developer`=7) AND (`answer_tocall`='accepted')) OR (`answer_tocall`='putonhold')
```

Comment: Whats the value of `$getUser` ? I think its not a single value. Its an array maybe

Comment: it is a number its 7

Comment: OK then I think the different type of `quotes` can be an issue. Can you try without quotes the column or table names ?

Comment: Are you sure your `LEFT JOIN` does not require any `ON` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$model = UserRequestWallet::find()
        ->with('mainRequest')
        ->where(['lead_developer' => $getUser])
        ->andWhere([
            'OR',
            ['answer_tocall' => 'accepted'],
            ['answer_tocall' => 'putonhold'],
        ])
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be work

```
$model = UserRequestWallet::find()
    ->where(['lead_developer' => $getUser])
    ->andWhere(['or', 'answer_tocall = accepted', 'answer_tocall = putonhold'])
    ->joinWith('mainRequest');
```

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#leftJoin()-detail) must set one more parametr for function `leftJoin( $table, $on = '', $params = [] )` 
And if you want use `static method find()` with method `joinWith(['relationName'])` of `ActiveRecords` you must define relation in model by correct wai, acording to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data).